why is で being used in 買ってくるか で
The following is my transcription from a podcast for learners of Japanese. The speaker is listing a few 家庭料理 dishes.
コロッケはね、どこのうちでも作るか, それかスーパーとかで買ってくるかで、よく食べる料理の一つだと思います。
Why is the で in bold being used?
As far as I can tell the two か (作るか...買ってくるか) are used to list two alternatives, a bit like, either... or... in English. I also think that それか is simply a way to "condense" to a single word the preceding sentence. I still can't figure out why で is used though...

it highlights the means to the next sentence or simply just connect them, it's eaten a lot, either by making it or buying it from the store.

Please try to avoid answering questions in the comment section. Comments are not for answers.

@aka thank you for answering. I believe it's a bit more specific here. I think I know what kind of で you're talking about and I've encountered it from time to time, but in this case, judging by the intonation / speech flow of the speaker it seems strongly connected to the preceding か. I suspect the usage is linked to this:
https://learnjapanesedaily.com/japanese-grammar-%E3%81%8B%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A7-kakade.html
even though the negative consequence the article mentions doesn't seem to apply here...

This で is a method-marking particle, corresponding to English "by" or "with".

コロッケはね、どこのうちでも作るか、それかスーパーとかで買ってくるかで、よく食べる料理の一つだと思います。
I think croquettes are one of those dishes that people commonly eat in every household, by either making them or buying them at supermarkets or such places.

Here, "作るか、それかスーパーとかで買ってくるか" forms a noun phrase, "either making them or buying them at supermarkets". それか is purely optional here, but it's used to emphasize the existence of the two options. It's like saying "..., or alternatively, ..." explicitly in English.
Note that か can nominalize a verb when used in the middle of a sentence to form an embedded question. When you don't use か, you need to use こと instead to nominalize a verb. A simplified version of your sentence would be:

コロッケは、スーパーで買ってくることで食べる料理の一つです。
Croquettes are one of those dishes that people eat by buying them at supermarkets.

See how か can work as a nominalizer in this example:

辞書を見るか検索するかしてください。
Either look it up in the dictionary or search for it.
辞書を見るか検索するかですぐ分かります。
You can quickly find out by either looking it up in the dictionary or searching for it.

